# Составление делового письма

Tags: документы

Делопроизводство в подразделениях МЧС России

**Задание.** Опишите требования, предъявляемые к составлению делового письма  в системе документирования в МЧС России, составьте текст делового письма о необходимости проведения бесед на противопожарную тематику в образовательном учреждении в соответствии с описанными требованиями.

Вот я подготовил! Что нужно поменять, если нужно? Я не совсем уверен, что тут все правильно.

О ознакомлении с документом

Уважаемый Николай Петрович!

С 10 июля 2012 г. вступает в силу Федеральный закон от 10.07.2012 N 117-ФЗ "О внесении изменений в Федеральный закон "Технический регламент о требованиях пожарной безопасности". В целях дальнейшей комфортной работы просим Вас ознакомить работников государственного пожарного надзора с данным документом.

Заместителя начальника
Главного управления                                     А.Н. Щуков

Исп. Щуков А. Н.
Тел. 8(342) 315-99-99

Comment: @sana159, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Я, конечно, не поручусь за МЧС, возможно, у них какие-то свои требования, но, по-моему, составлено вполне грамотно и по существу.
Я бы ничего менять не стала, у Вас все хорошо.

Comment: Спасибо вам!

Answer (score 1):

1. В названии темы лучше предлог "Об" (ознакомлении).
2. В названии закона применены вложенные кавычки. Наружные кавычки должны отличаться по типу ("ёлочки").
3. ЗаместителЬ.
4. Государственный п. н. - первое слово с большой буквы (если наименование органа).

Comment: Благодарю вас!

Answer (score 0):

1. В названии темы лучше предлог "Об" (ознакомлении)
2. В названии закона применены вложенные кавычки. Наружные кавычки должны отличаться по типу ("ёлочки").
3. ЗаместителЬ
4. Государственный п. н. - первое слово с большой буквы (если наименование органа)

Answer (score 0):

Федеральный закон от 10.07.2012 уже вступил в силу 10.07.1012, поэтому текст должен быть примерно таким: ...В связи с вступлением в силу Федерального закона от 10.17.2012 № 117-Ф3 " О внесении изменений..." прошу ознакомить работников (название организации) с данным документом.

Заместитель начальника 
главного управления                                                А.Н. Щуков

Исп. Карасев. Тел. 8 944...

Цель ознакомления с законом указывать не следует, если он всех касается. 
У заместителя начальника главка обязан быть исполнитель его директив.